# Time to prepare for Fundamentals of Quantum Computation Using Qiskit v0.2X?

Tags: qiskit

I am a novice programmer with some skills in C++, C#, and Python.

Would anybody have an idea about the average time needed to prepare for this certification?
(Fundamentals of Quantum Computation Using Qiskit v0.2X )

If you can share your own experience, that would be of great value as well.

Thanks in advance.

Ruben

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Your question could be interpreted as opinion-based. Consider editing it to prompt fact-based answers to ensure it is not closed. The time required entirely depends on your specific background in quantum, python programming, and experience using Qiskit. To gauge whether you are adequately prepared, look over the [recommended prerequisite skills](https://www.ibm.com/certify/cert?id=C0010300) and at some [sample exams](https://www.ibm.com/certify/exam?id=C1000-112).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the site is about topical knowledge about quantum computation and quantum information, not about career-advise-like questions

Comment: @glS where would someone ask such a question, is there another forum somewhere which can be opinion based ?

Comment: @BrockenDuck well, I'd say a forum is the right place to ask this sort of question, yes. Stackexchange is not a forum. Being this related to qiskit, don't they have some sort of dedicated forum?

Comment: @glS I couldn't find a non-event related one. But the reddit quantum computing community could answer such a qustion with their discord server.

Comment: It could also be worth asking in the Qiskit Slack (linked from the bottom of [the website](https://qiskit.org/))

Comment: Guys, thank you for your time and answers addressing my question. It seems reasonable that this question might not be appropriate for this space. I agree with that point of view. I hope to get in touch with you in the near future. Ruben.